# Makefile directories error

Tags: c++, makefile, subdirectory

Im using this code in the makefile, all is going good but the last line.
My code folder looks like this:

Project/bin     -> For executable files

Project/build   -> For .o files

Project/include -> For .hpp files

Project/src     -> For .cpp files

Makefile path: Project/Makefile

```
# Compiler #
CC       = g++
DEBUG    = -g
LFLAGS   =
CFLAGS   = -Wall

# Directories #
SRCDIR   = src/
INCDIR   = include/
BUILDDIR = build/
BINDIR   = bin/

# Objects #
OBJ_NAMES = main.o dfa.o dfaException.o state.o
OBJS       = $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR), $(OBJ_NAMES))

# Output #
TARGET = $(BINDIR)pract3

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(TARGET)

$(BUILDDIR)%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS)  $(LFLAGS) -c $< -o $(BUILDDIR)$($(notdir  $<):.cpp=.o)
```

The problem is in "`$(BUILDDIR)$($(notdir  $<):.cpp=.o)`". What Im trying to do here is:

1. $< contains "`src/mysrc.cpp`" so with `$(notdir $<)` I get
   "`mysrc.cpp`"
2. Now, I want to change the file extension to `.o`, so I use  `$($(notdir $<):.cpp=.o)` And I should get "`mysrc.o`". But this part is not working:

   g++    -c src/main.cpp -o build/

   Assembler messages:

   Fatal error: can't create build/: Permission denied

   Makefile:25: recipe for target 'build/main.o' failed

   make: *** [build/main.o] Error 1
3. I use `$(BUILDDIR)` To get "`build/mysrc.o`"

Why does `$($(notdir $<):.cpp=.o)` somehow delete the file name ?

And now that Im here. I've learned to use make some days ago. Is there something that I should improve here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(notdir)` operates on strings.

`$(X:Y=Z)` operates on the **value** of the `X` variable.

So follow your expansions when `$<` is `src/mysrc.cpp`

```
$($(notdir  $<):.cpp=.o)
```

becomes

```
$(mysrc.cpp:.cpp=.o)
```

Is that how you would write that?

No, you would write `$(<:.cpp=.o)`.

So invert your operations.

```
 $(notdir  $(<:.cpp=.o))
```

Or, even better and simpler than that just use `$@` since that's the target you are building and what you want to create.

```
$(CC) $(CCFLAGS)  $(LFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```